# How to Selection Sort some structs

Tags: c++, c

I have to put in order some files sorting by year(`ano`), month(`mes`), day(`dia`) but i could only sort by year.

```
struct registro{ 

    short ano;
    char mes;
    char dia;
    char hora;
    char min;
    char seg;
};

void selectionSort(struct registro *dados, int n){   

    int i, j, menor;
    struct registro aux;
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        menor = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if(dados[menor].ano > dados[j].ano)
            {
                menor = j;
            }
            if(i != menor){
                aux = dados[i];
                dados[i] = dados[menor];
                dados[menor] = aux;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you are programming in C++, you don't need `struct` when declaring function parameters; use the tag or struct name.  Same when declaring variables.

Comment: Since you tagged with C++, you should pass structures by reference or `const` reference if your function doesn't modify the parameter.  (The C and C++ are different languages, C doesn't have references).

Answer (score 1):

Check signarturee of standard C library [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) function

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

As you can see the last parameter is a pointer to a function (callback) which is used to compare values. You are using fixed gretter operator `dados[menor].ano > dados[j].ano` in your selectionSort. In order to make it generic you can make next modification:

```
static registroYearCmp(struct registro* lhs, struct registro *rhs) 
{
  return lhs->ano - rhs->ano;
}

static registroMonthCmp(struct registro* lhs, struct registro *rhs) 
{
  return lhs->mes - rhs->mes;
}

static registroDayCmp(struct registro* lhs, struct registro *rhs) 
{
 return lhs->dia - rhs->dia;
}

void selectionSort(struct registro *dados, int n, *(compare_registro)(struct registro*, struct registro*) ){   
......
            if( compare_registro(dados[menor],dados[j]) > 0 )
......
}
.......
 /* Sort by year */
 selectionSort(dados, 16,  registroYearCmp);
 /* Sort by month */
 selectionSort(dados, 16,  registroMonthCmp);
 /* Sort by day */
 selectionSort(dados, 16,  registroDayCmp);
```